# Apache Pig - Jython UDF Memory Error

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig, jython

I'm using Jython to write my Python UDF in pig but I'm encountering memory issues when the input to my UDF is massive (i.e. it exceeds the memory allocated to my JVM). In the Pig documentation, functions such as COUNT, MAX etc overcome this by using the Algebraic and more importantly the Accumulator interface. The Accumulator interface allows data from Pig to be sent in chunks to the UDF and this is suitable to my problem. Does anyone have any examples of doing this with Jython? (or any ideas of streaming the input to Python) Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Python UDFs do not support such optimizations interfaces:
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/udf.html#udfs